# Chart not resizing according to it's container Highcharts reactjs

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

Here's the live example URL:
https://react-bjtmoe.stackblitz.io/

I am using `highcharts-react-official` npm package to create charts. When click on the blue line, The container size will increase but the chart inside it is not increasing it's size according to container. Here's: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bjtmoe

**Code Explanation:**

The code itself is very easy to understand as I have written it from scratch to make it easy to understand that what the problem is. I have created two components, chart.js & chart_container.js. The chart_container.js file is basically a wrapper around the charts. I have data logic here in this file & after processing, I am passing data and DOM element to my chart.js file which will render the actual chart to the DOM.

I created ref inside `chart.js` file and passed it to the HighchartsReact component and after Highcharts rendered to the DOM, I returned the ref to the chart container and called `reflow()` method there. reflow method is available but I am not getting why it's not increasing or decreasing its size according to container size.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `reflow` method at the end of your `onclick` event function callback:

```
  elm.onclick = function() {
    elm.style.height = "400px";
    elm.style.width = "600px";

    chart.reflow();
  };
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pcfzsu?file=src%2Fchart_container.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow

Comment: I am rendering chart inside loop. So, I have solved the issue by assigning different ref to every chart component and call the reflow method from that ref.